# MySQL WHERE IN () + AND , PDO returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, where-in

following query returns all wanted results if entered in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT     postid, voting 
FROM       postvotes 
WHERE      userid = 1 
AND        postid IN 
                   (1007,1011,1012,1013,1014,
                   1015,1016,1017,1018,1019,1020,1021,1023,1025,1026,
                   1027,1028,1029,1030,1031)
```

But PDO fails to fetchAll(). It just returns the first match like fetch().

What's wrong?

PHP Code:

```
private function userPostVotings( $postIDs ) {

// $postIDs contains a string like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...
// generated through implode(',', idArray)

  try {

    $userPostVote = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT postid, voting 
    FROM postvotes 
    WHERE userid = ? 
    AND postid IN ( ? )');

    $userPostVote->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $userPostVote->execute( array( $this->_requester['id'], $postIDs ) );

    while ( $res = $userPostVote->fetch() ) { 

        var_dump( $res ); 

    }

  } catch (\PDOException $p) {}

}
```

If I echo out the query used in this method and fire it through phpmyadmin I get the correct number of results. However PDO gives just the first. No matter if a loop with fetch() or fetchAll().

Comment: if the query ran fine, then is php error, post you php code, I guess you are talking about php pdo extension

Comment: it was asked zillion times already

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not PDO's fetchAll() of course, but your query.

Which is not

```
IN (1007,1011,1012,1013,1014)
```

but

```
IN ('1007,1011,1012,1013,1014')
```

and of course it will find only first value as this string will be cast to the first number

One have to create a query with placeholders representing every array member, and then bind this array values for execution:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (?,?,?)");
$stm->execute($ids);
```

To make this query more flexible, it's better to create a string with ?s dynamically:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bind array in prepared statements in PDO.

Reference:
[Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: There is no array. Implode returns a string of numbers separated by a comma. This string is passed to the method.